# How can I get web service method being called by HttpContext?

Tags: c#, web-services, http, httpcontext

I have web service with 40 different web methods.
Can I get in my web service the Method that the request sent from using HttpContext?

I need it because I have abstract general command that all the methods activate and I have access only to HttpContext.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correct your question you can use [PathInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.pathinfo.aspx) property of the `HttpRequest`:

```
string methodName = HttpContext.Current.Request.PathInfo;
```

The string `methodName` will be the method name with the slash prefix (`/`): `"/MyWebMethod"`.

Comment: Thanks but it returns me empty string and not the method name

Comment: @DorCohen: How looks the URL which you use on the client? Like `someBase/MyWebService.asmx/MyWebMethod`? Do you use any URL mapping module in `<system.webserver>` part of `web.config`?

Comment: No just: someBase/MyWebService.asmx

Comment: @DorCohen: How you specify one from 40 different web methods which you want to call currently? How looks `HttpContext.Current.Request.Path` in your case?

Comment: It's ok now.. Can I get also the parameters I sent?

Comment: @DorCohen: If you use HTTP GET then you can use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Params`, but in case of HTTP POST I am not sure how you can access *all* parameters in the simple way.

Comment: what about HttpContext.Current.Request.Form ?

Comment: @JiříHerník: Sorry, but before posting of your suggestion you should test it. In my tests the `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form` is empty. It can be that some easy way do exist. I wrote just that I don't know the *simple* way.

Answer (score -1):

You probably need:

```
HttpContext.Current
```

But be sure you've the ASPX compatibility mode turned on, otherwise you'll not be able to access that property

You can also save the name of the function into the Items array like this:

```
void myServiceMethod()
{
  HttpContext.Current.Items["MethodName"] = "myServiceMethod";
  // ...
  // here comes your method implementation
}
```

and then you can anywhere read the `HttpContext.Current.Items["MethodName"]`

colection HttpContext.Current.Items is valid always only for current request, so you can use it as a storage for any request related information.

When the request is responded, it's garbage.

Comment: It's give me only the web service asmx path, not the specific method - http://dc.dc.com/AgentWS/AgentService.asmx

Comment: then you can save the method name into HttpContext.Current.Items as a first thing in the method implementation.
You can then read the name anywhere in the scope of current request.